# Materialised views Google BigQuery

Tags: database, database-design, google-bigquery, materialized-views

I know that Google BigQuery does not support materialised views, only logical ones. Are there any methods for simulating materialised views in Google BiqQuery?

The approach I’m thinking of adopting is to write a periodic task that manually reads data from a table, transforms it and the writes it to a target table. If there are better approaches, I’d like to know about them.

Comment: Well the way to approximate materialized views in MySQL, another database which also does not support them directly, is to just use a temporary table.  So, you may try creating a temporary table in Big Query to serve as a materialized view.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the approach I'm thinking of adopting, with a periodic task that reads from database and then writes it to a target table. How temporary the target table will be is TBD, but I was hoping for a more elegant approach.

Comment: Both using temporary request or using periodic tasks such as Cron Jobs are the only solutions I can think of. There's a public [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62244996) in case you want to push it.